# How to block dashes in the bottom of the table

Tags: php, sorting, block, tablesorter

So, my question is in the title.
I have a table with this data :

9
6
5
'-'
5
2.3
987
'-'
'-'
54.2
41
52
66
55

Note: I surround my dash with simple quote to have a best readability.
and when I use the tablesorter, all works fine, but either my dashes are on the top and my number are sorted asc and conversely .

OR, I would like my dashes stay on the bottom of my table , whatsoever asc or desc sort..

It's my simple js :

```
 $("#table_conso_visu").tablesorter({
        widgets        : ['zebra', 'columns'],
        usNumberFormat : false,
        sortReset      : true,
        sortRestart    : true,
               })
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could see if your tablesorter plugin supports custom comparator functions. If so, write one which always sorts the dash below any number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to resolve my probleme.
I create a filter which return me a minimum value .
So my dashes stay on the bottom when my sort is asc et stay on top when my sort is desc.
I think it's more logical that the dash is on the top when my sort is desc beacause it's like if i put 0 ;)

So it's my filter :

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
            id: "dashSorter",
            format: function(s) {
              return ($.trim(s) === '-') ? Number.MIN_VALUE : $.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(/[,:]/g, ""));
            },
            type: "numeric"
          });
```

i put ':' in my regex beacause i have time in format HH:mm:ss (you can remove it)
and my script top sort my table :

```
$("table[name=table_sorter]").tablesorter({

        // initialize zebra striping and filter widgets
        widgets :  ['zebra', 'filter'],
        headers : {
            1 : {sorter:'dashSorter'},
            2 : {sorter:'dashSorter'},
            3 : {sorter:'dashSorter'}
        },
        widgetOptions : {
            // css class applied to the table row containing the filters & the inputs within that row
            filter_cssFilter   : 'tablesorter-filter',

            // If there are child rows in the table (rows with class name from "cssChildRow" option)
            // and this option is true and a match is found anywhere in the child row, then it will make that row
            // visible; default is false
            filter_childRows   : false,

            // if true, filters are collapsed initially, but can be revealed by hovering over the grey bar immediately
            // below the header row. Additionally, tabbing through the document will open the filter row when an input gets focus
            filter_hideFilters : false,

            // Set this option to false to make the searches case sensitive
            filter_ignoreCase  : true,

            // jQuery selector string of an element used to reset the filters
            filter_reset : '.reset',

            // Delay in milliseconds before the filter widget starts searching; This option prevents searching for
            // every character while typing and should make searching large tables faster.
            filter_searchDelay : 300,

            // Set this option to true to use the filter to find text from the start of the column
            // So typing in "a" will find "albert" but not "frank", both have a's; default is false
            filter_startsWith  : false
        }
    });
```

i hope that help people and see you soon ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you use my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) you can use the [`stringTo`](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#stringto) option to set where text strings sort within numeric columns.

Check out [this demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-options-headers-digits-strings.html).

Comment: Thank for your answer , i tryed to use : class="{ string: 'bottom'}" , and i put the jquery.metadata.js betwen my <head> , but my dashes don't stay to the bottom of my table